# why xeyes can't open display on raspberry pi with local display and variable set, no ssh

Tags: display, screen, raspberry-pi-os-buster

Hi I'm trying to use xeyes on a rapsberry Pi equiped with an LCD screen. I'm using Raspberry Pi Os Lite Legacy ( a debian buster) and i've installed the packages x11-apps. But when I try a DISPLAY=:0 xeyes command I get the Error : Can't open display. I'm not trying to use ssh. What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: You need an X server for this. The easiest way is not to use the "Lite" version but the full OS

Comment: Yeah that could be a way of solving it but is there no way to get an X server on "Lite" ? I though that x11-apps was the X server system

Comment: No, if I'm not misstaken, x11-apps is just a bunch of small gui tools (such as xeyes, which is nice just for testing that the Gui works). The packages you need are `xserver-xorg` and `xinit`. And then you need to start it with `startx`.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for clarifying and dropping clues on what's going on. Yes you were right,  x11-apps is just a bunch of small gui tools. So I installed xserver-xorg, xinit and x11-xserver-utils and then launched startx and got xeyes to work. Now I'm looking on a way to launch startx and a GUI app like xeyes at boot